# Is it possible to prevent that a popup be opened directly as opposed to being opened by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

The application I'm working on relies on many popups. Those popups rely themselves on query strings. If someone can just type the url in the browser address bar, the page will throw an error as the query strings values are dynamically constructed.

```
function myFunction(id)
{
    window.open("mypopup.aspx?id=" + id); 
}
```

Is there a why to prevent the page from displaying if the requester of the page is not a Javascript? If someone type something like:

```
https://mycompanyname.com/path/mypopup.aspx
```

It shouldn't let the user do so. Or, at least check whether the requester is not javascript so I can display a message or redirect the user to a different page? Otherwise, without all those pieces of data needed to construct a request, the page will throw an exception.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why do an actual popup window? Standard practices now are to use a popup within the context of the web page itself via a CSS and JavaScript framework. Examples are Bootstrap modals, jQuery Dialogs etc.

Comment: It's an existing application. I'm just working on.

Comment: Why not take the opportunity to correct an outdated practice that results in a poor user experience?

Comment: Believe me when I'm telling you that all that has been settled. As a relatively recent developer, I'm accustomed to tools like jQuery and Bootsrap. However, in this project, which is a conversion from ASP Classic to ASP.NET, the client wants the new application to look like the older one, to behave like the older one, and the code to be kept as close as possible the one that was there, no fancy things, just pure JS, CSS, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validate the query string directly in myPopup.aspx, if something is missing just redirect or display a message.

Use the Request.QueryString collection to validate in myPopup.aspx.

There is no easy way to validate if the request came from javascript as far as I know.  You could try creating a token to validate that the sender is the one you expect, but if you only need to validate the parameters, no need to worry about who is sending the request.

Answer (score 1):

The page cannot differentiate how it was requested, if both requests come from a same browser.

However, you can include in query string to differentiate them.

For example,

```
window.open("mypopup.aspx?request=javascript&id=" + id);
```

If a user intentionally type in `https://mycompanyname.com/path/mypopup.aspx?request=javascript`, so be it. I won't worry about it.

Comment: This also could be an answer because knowing that the popup has been created by JS might means that all the params will be present.

Answer (score 1):

Popups are browser windows too. So it will be tricky to check if the window requesting the page is normal window or popup.

1. You should restrict the users to see on what url the popup is being opened you can hide the address bar. So user can not copy or know the what's in the url. 
   `window.open('/pageaddress.html','winname','directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=350');`
2. Setup a token based validation. Make request to server(`Ajax request`) to get a random token(with one time validation mechanism and expire it), You can send the token in the query string and validate it on server if it's same issued token. Identify if the requested page have valid token(popup) otherwise deny the request or show error message. Think of how `captcha` works, you just need to do it programmatically.

Though it's also not the best solution as token information can be sniffed through network traffic tracker tools like fiddler but it's will work to prevent manual requests.

Comment: You cannot hide address bar in new browsers anymore due to security reason.